# Android HCE with secure element source code example

Tags: android, nfc, hce

Hy... I'm trying to find a source code that implementing android HCE with secure element. I have read these two articles right here :

http://developer.android.com/samples/CardEmulation/index.html
http://blog.opendatalab.de/hack/2013/11/07/android-host-card-emulation-with-acr122/

But those just shows an Android HCE without secure element. I have read another blogs too, but none of them shows me the source code example. Just some explanations about Secure elements or else....

Can someone help me with this...?? I need an android source code example with secure element included...And ooowh.. I dont need third party librari, for example from SEEK FOR ANDROID/SIM ALLIANCE or usmile project...

Thanks in adnvace.... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense. You can't have HCE (Host Based Card Emulation) using a secure element. The sole purpose of HCE is, that you don't have to access the secure element.

What you'll probably want is to put a card emulation application into the secure element.

Bad news first: You will very likely not be able to do this because you need to authenticate with the secure element to install any applications. It is highly unlikely that you'll ever get the keys.

Anyway:

To get access to the secure element you have to use a non public API. The relevant files are available in the android source tree at:

```
<android-sdk-base>frameworks/base/nfc-extras
```

With a bit of luck you can access the classes provided using java reflection. Once you have access to the classes you'll need an instance of the class NfcExecutionEnvironment. This class provides the function:

```
byte[] transceive(byte[] in)
```

This is the communication channel to the secure element. The function expects ISO7816-4 commands, and you can expect it to behave like a JavaCard SmartCard with NFC extensions. Given that you have the keys to authenticate to the SE you should be able to upload and install ordinary JavaCard .cap files directly to the SE.

Using the SEEK API is probably easier and more flexible as it may allow you to install applets to a NFC-SIM card as well.

Comment: Thaks for your answer Mr. Nils and I'm sorry for misunderstanding of my question,,... Ummm... in this page : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html, there is an ilustration of using HCE with secure element (figure 1). But when I try to find a source code example for that implementation, I can't... The only source code that I have found is just HCE without SE implementation... :-)

And from that figure 1, I thought that there is an API of NFC that provided by google for accessing/sending any data,...

Comment: And thanks so much for information about the location of nfc-extras. I have trying to build an android ROM from source (even though it's still fail.. :D), so may be I can learn that nfc-extras from that android source code tree...

Comment: @Poipo That picture shows card emulation using SE, not host based card emulation (big difference!).

Comment: Oooowh.... Ummm... My task is to use android as a tag (or HCE) that connect to SE through NFC controller like in that site (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html), but the problem is I can't find any example source code..... You said that card emulation using SE is different from HCE emulation, I don't know much about that, I just need the source code example for Card emulation using SE or HCE emulation with SE.... :-)

Thanks mr. Nils.... :-)

Comment: You need a lot more than just "source code example for Card emulation using SE". You have to learn a *huge* framework, the tools and the workflow how to do it. Even if you had the source-code you would have no idea how to compile that source-code into a applet that can be installed in the SE let alone the keys to do so.

Comment: And this is essential as well: http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/embedded/card/overview/index.html

Comment: Iyapz, that's right mr.Nils... I have read a lot of articles, including from ETSI or ISO, global platform, SEEK for Google, etc.... But it's not the source code... :-)

Comment: And oowwh.. Almost all of documents just tell the specifications, rules, usage, functions, drawbacks, requirements, methods, etc.. I'm kinda can't understand all of them without learning the source code directly... :-)

Comment: You want example code: Here you go: https://umer555.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/java-card-hello-world-applet/ See? It does not help you anything without understanding the infrastructure.

Comment: Ummm... I think, I have seen that blog before mr.Nils,, But thanks for your suggestion... :-)